# Force Tabhost to initiate Activity (refresh)

Tags: android, android-tabhost

To put it simply. From a context menu on a TabActivity how can I initiate executing the intent for the current tab? I am trying to force a refresh.

The tabs all initiate activities displaying a subset of people names.  While in one list you call up an edit activity which allows you to associate the name to one of the other lists in the TabHost.  Using the back button to get back to the tabhost (onResume fires) and the list has not updated.  I would like to have a context menu item to refresh the current tab.

I know about using one activity for all the views in a tabhost but for many reasons I have not chosen that method.

Answer (score 2):

You can also try adding a flag to the intent when you set up the tabs in the first place.

```
    Intent i = new Intent().setClass(this, YourClass.class)
.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);

    TabHost.TabSpec spec = tabHost.newTabSpec("name")
.setIndicator("Class",res.getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_tab_something))
.setContent(intent);

    Tabhost tabHost.addTab(spec);
```

Comment: adding the flag actually worked for me. Don't know why they voted your answer down though. Thanks!

Comment: Well it works. The flag reloads the tab every time you visit it so all you would have to do it switch tabs with the setCurrentTab command and then set back.

Comment: @user522559, porbably because this doesn't solve the problem of refreshing the active/visible tab. User needs to switch tabs. Overall the flag seems useless as one can simply use the onResume() callback in such scenario.

Answer (score -1):

I think due to the activity lifecycle, you will have some problems 'restarting' the activity ([Activity lifecycle - startActivity()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3991606/activity-lifecycle-startactivity-with-extras)) - if you were to move any logic you have inside the onCreate method into another method, then call the method from onCreate and onResume, so it rebuilds the tab content for you.

Alternatively you could add a menu item to call this method, so onCreate calls the logic method on first run, and your user can call it from the menu to refresh the contents.

Comment: I put this problem on hold, but now I am revisiting it.  I don't know how to tell the activity to refresh since the options menu is attached to the TabHost and not the activity being displayed by the tabhost.  This is a real big problem for me now.

Comment: SOLVED I had to do two setCurrentTab()  commands, one to a different tab and then again back to the tab that was in view.  It happened very fast so I guess I can live with this ugly hack.

Comment: Jim, I too perform two setCurrentTab()'s in order to "preload" the content in my second tab first. If I don't, then I receive a NullPointerException when I try to call a public method of the second tab (from the first tab, without having opened the second tab yet).  Works with no problems, I'm just wondering if there is a more elegant way...

Comment: I guess another alternative that is a bit less hackish is to only call setCurrentTab() once, and use getLocalActivityManager().startActivity("secondID",
    new Intent(this, SecondTabActivity.class));